# Installing a package from source?

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm trying to install an older version of the phylogenetics package "geiger" on `R`.  I'm on a Windows XP machine. I've tried the following construction:

```
install.packages(C:\geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

And every permutation I can think of for it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: the error returned is:

```
Error: unexpected input in "install.packages(C:\"
```

Comment: You need to use double \\ or a single /.

Answer (score 5):

shouldn't you pass the file name as a string (or better yet w/ `file.path`)? e.g. `install.packages(file.path("geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz"), repos = NULL, type = "source")` Remember that installing packages you need to pass a string where loading libraries you can pass an unquoted name (or a string).

**Responding to your comment here so I can have formatting**

So you wrote `install.packages(C:\Rfiles("geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz"), repos = NULL, type = "source")`. Remember that the first argument to `install.packages` has to be a character vector. What you've passed in is `C:\Rfiles("geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz")` which isn't really anything. Take a look at `help(file.path)` and `help(install.packages)` to see some examples of how to specify the file path. In this specific case you should try:

```
g.path <- file.path("C:", "Rfiles", "geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz")
install.packages(g.path, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

That's (as best as I can tell) the absolute path to your package, with no worrying about the backslash/forwardslash issue.

Comment: Thank you, Adam.  I used the following constructions: **install.packages(C:\Rfiles("geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz"), repos = NULL, type = "source")** and **install.packages(C:\Rfiles\("geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz"), repos = NULL, type = "source")**, and neither of them seem to work.

Comment: I'm completely stymied.  I tried this, and no luck.  I've even gone back to earlier versions of both R and geiger.  Same errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? In this case it is important to run the commands as I typed in the edit. If you're getting a syntax error it is probably how the command is inputted and not in R or gieger.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks very much for your suggestions.  I finally solved it through the use of another package: "repmis".  This package includes a command called "InstallOldPackages", which does just that.  You can specify the package name and the version number you need.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you typically need to switch backslashes `\` to forwardslashes `/` or you will have an error.  I suspect:

```
install.packages("C:/geiger_1.3-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

will work for you.  This is probably the simplest way.